# Xmission Tor node Warrant info?

Tags: exit-relays

I have a client who is thinking of switching to Xmission (a local Utah company) for website servers, and was reading a Guardian article about Xmission's stance on privacy, and I'm very impressed. They take people's privacy very seriously and have sided with the constitution as far as I can tell, but there's one issue I'm wondering about:

They have a webpage that shows the requests they get and the outcome, such as but I noticed some of them say "No Info" and they're only for anon.xmission.com, which is a Tor "exit" node, whatever that means. I don't use Tor, but I'm curious what "No Info" means, why it's only for those requests, and what exactly Xmission is doing in regards to that. Are they complying to warrantless searches or are they being honest that they have no info on it? I'm not even sure what info exactly they don't have (contextually). They would know what their response and its outcome would be.

Here's their outcome page: http://xmission.com/transparency

Here's the Guardian article: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jul/09/xmission-isp-customers-privacy-nsa

I found this forum looking for Xmission Tor info; sorry if this isn't a good enough place for this question. Xmission's customer support isn't available right now and it seems I need to have an account with them just to contact them online.

Are there other sites like this exit Tor node that I should be aware of as a webserver admin?

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to understand what Tor is, which can be done here: https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en

When they say "No info" It's because they don't have any data, as per the webpage that was/is hosted on the domain:

> This router maintains no logs of any of the Tor traffic, so there is little that can be done to trace either legitimate or illegitimate traffic (or to filter one from the other). Attempts to seize this router will accomplish nothing.

If all else fails, you can try emailing the owner of Xmission for clarification, they're very active with these issues.

There are many Tor exit nodes, I would recommend reading up on what Tor is, and how it operates before deciding to act.

Comment: I do understand what Tor is (a browser to surf anonymously), so just because I don't understand all the details doesn't mean I don't understand what Tor is. Thank you for your guidance though.